# Placing of output parameter parsing from stored procedure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I encountered this error due to an apparently misplaced parsing of an output stored procedure parameter.

> The out parameter 'whichID' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Code:

```
public static bool CreateFilmTest(string param1, string param2, out int whichID)
{
            DbCommand com = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandText = "CatalogCreateFilmTest";

            DbParameter param = com.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@param1";
            param.Value = param1;
            param.DbType = DbType.String;
            param.Size = 200;
            com.Parameters.Add(param);
            ..........            
            param = com.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Fid";
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
            com.Parameters.Add(param);

            int result = -1;

            try
            {
                result = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(com);

                whichID = Int32.Parse(com.Parameters["@Fid"].Value.ToString());

            }
            catch
            {
                // ....
            }


           return (result >= 1);
}
```

If I place the: `whichID = Int32.Parse(com.Parameters["@Fid"].Value.ToString());`
line **immediately before the return line**, the method executes successfully and gives the correct result.

However, if I place it within the try brackets, it gives the error mentioned in the beginning.

**Why so?**

My first choice was put it **inside the try bracket**, because IF for any reason the `ExecuteNonQuery` fails, it doesn't make sense to handle its output parameter (`whichID`). Therefore I saw best to couple the two elements (execution of procedure and handling of output parameter from procedure) inside the try block, that triggers in case of error the elegant handling of such situation inside `catch`.

Your input is much appreciated. Thanks. Anna

Comment: If you place your `whichID =....` line inside the try..catch - you'll need to initialize the `whichID` **out** parameter with a value somewhere outside the `try...catch` block (or inside the `catch` portion). The **out** parameter **must always** be assigned a value

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is that there is no reasonably certain assignment happening if you place it within the try. You can get around this by assigning it a default value earlier in the method (say, setting it to zero on the first line).

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves this is because the `try` is compiled in such a way as to include an inner `try`, meaning that the program flow might not correctly step into the `try` before proceeding onwards (even though you usually assume that `try` doesn't itself interrupt program flow the same as, say, `if` does).

This would then trigger the compiler check against `out` parameters being assigned before exiting the method.

Simply default the value at the very top of the method.

---

Memory does serve... the language specification knows all.

[12.3.3.15 Try-catch-finally statements](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (specifically assignment analysis for `try-catch-finally`).

> Definite assignment analysis for a try-catch-finally statement of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> try [try-block]
> catch ( … ) [catch-block-1]
> …
> catch ( … ) [catch-block-n]
> finally [finally-block]
> ```
>
> is done as if the statement were a try-finally statement enclosing a
>   try-catch statement:
>
> ```
> try {
> try [try-block]
> catch ( … ) [catch-block-1]
> …
> catch ( … ) [catch-block-n]
> }
> finally [finally-block]
> ```

An example:

```
class A
{
    static void F() {
        int i, j;
        try {
            goto LABEL;
            // neither i nor j definitely assigned
            i = 1;
            // i definitely assigned
        }
        catch {
            // neither i nor j definitely assigned
            i = 3;
            // i definitely assigned
        }
        finally {
            // neither i nor j definitely assigned
            j = 5;
            // j definitely assigned
        }
        // i and j definitely assigned
        LABEL:;
        // j definitely assigned
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get that error is due to the way try/catch is handled by the compiler.  A try/catch block is a conditional statement in a sense.  The code within it only exectues if the code before it did not throw an exception, and the code itself only finishes executing if it does not throw an exception itself.

If you are only defining a variable within the try (or only within the catch(es)), then you cannot be sure that those lines of code will run.  If your variable is only defined within the try-block, then it could possibly be skipped if there is an exception before, or on the line that does the defining.  If your variable is only defined in the catch clause, then it will be skipped if no exceptions occur.

**You are best off either declaring a default value before you enter the try-catch block, or declaring a failure value within your catch clause.**